# My query doesn't run

Tags: php

I have some view in a php project.  I call a method by HTML submit button, but the method isn't run and I don't understand why. The method contains a query what is uploading 2 text to a SQL database.

Here is my method:

```
public function uploadCtrl() {
    if(isset($_POST['send_note'])){
    $title =$_POST['title_of_note'];
    $text =$_POST['text_of_note'];
    $id = $_SESSION['user_logged_status'];

    var_dump($title, $text, $id);

    $database->noteToDatabase($title, $text, $id);
}
```

here is the view:

```
public function  uploadNote(){
?>
    <form action='' method='post'><br>
          Title:<input type='text' name='title_of_note'><br>
          Text:<input id='long_text' type='text' name='text_of_note'><br>
          <input type='submit' name='send' value='SEND'><br>
          <a href='?send_note'>Note save</a>
    </form>
<?}
```

and the query method:

```
public function noteToDatabase($title, $text, $id){
    $stmt = $this->conn->query("INSERT INTO note (title, text,user_id) VALUES ('$title','$text','$id')");
    var_dump($stmt);
}
```

I call the method here:

```
     if(isset($_POST['new_note'])){

            $ctrl = new note_ctrl();
            $ctrl->uploadNoteToDatabase();
           // $ctrl->uploadCtrl();  

        }
```

I checked the post method using Mozilla Firebug and it looked okay, but this method never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST['send']` instead of `$_POST['send_note']`

```
public function uploadCtrl(){

          if(isset($_POST['send'])){
```

Comment: Doesn't work and sorry about it , i've written wrong the code , it was just a typo ,because i tried it a link instead of submit button , but it also doesn't work.(The link name was the send_note)

Answer (score 0):

If your methods are in one class. You can try to call your `uploadCtrl()` method in view.

```
public function  uploadNote(){
if(isset($_POST['send'])){$this->uploadCtrl()}
?>
    <form action='' method='post'><br>
    Title:<input type='text' name='title_of_note'><br>
    Text:<input id='long_text' type='text' name='text_of_note'><br>
    <input type='submit' name='send' value='SEND'><br>
    <a href='?send_note'>Note save</a>
    </form>

<?
}
```

If view is in another class, you need to make your method `public function uploadCtrl(){` static like `public static function uploadCtrl(){`, so then you can call it in view like `note_ctrl::uploadCtrl()`

Answer (score -1):

try mentioning the method name in `action` parameter of `form` tag

```
form action="note_ctrl/uploadCtrl" method="post"
```

Thanks

Are you using any framework?